# Symbols in GCP Monitoring Line Chart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, linechart, google-cloud-monitoring

I am working on google cloud monitoring dashboards and there are some symbols in line charts which i am not able to understand.

[image]

[image]

**Can anyone please explain what does these symbols mean `+`, `x`, `^` etc and how are they used in the context of the charts ?**

Answer (score 0):

These are just some legends available to make your graphs look elegant and easy to distinguish. There is a [official reference document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/chart-view-options) available. These icons are just there for better understanding and you can use proper legends based on your necessity.